# Why won't the symbol "&" work within my scss code?

Tags: html, css, sass

Hey I've just started on building a website for my portfolio but i instantly ran into a problem. I've never worked with Sass before, only basic css so i don't know all the quirks and tricks. But i watched a video to learn more about it and to learn more about creating my responsive website. I came to using the symbol "&" in the context of changing some elements on a navigation-bar. The code is as follows:

```
header {

    nav {
        padding: 40px;   
     
    }        
    &__links {

        a {   
            font-size: $font-sm;
        
        }  
    }
    a:hover {
        color: $darkblue;

    }

}
```

The "a:hover" and "nav" works perfectly but the "&__links" and everything inside it doesn't work. The file that this code is located in is linked to a main "Style.css" page by using the "import" function, Which in turn is linked to the main html Index page via this command: "". I appreciate any help I can get concerning my problem here and I can send more code if needed. But i believe this is the only code needed as i have tried to isolate the problem. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `&` does work. It generates something that looks like this:

```
header__links a {
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

There is no `<header_links>` element allowed in HTML though.

Likely you wanted to generate a different selector entirely.

Comment: No, the "header__links" is a class name in the html file, it's the class name of the "nav". So I'm trying to change some things about the items "<a>" inside the "<nav class = "header__links" >".

Comment: @TheBigChung — You can't add `header` and `__links` and get `.header__links`: The `.` has to come from somewhere.

Comment: Oh, I thought that was the reason for using the "&" that you add "header" and "__links" and get "header__links". So whats the use of "&" for?

Comment: That **is** the purpose of `&`. It gives you, in this case, `header__links` (a type selector). It **doesn't** give you `.header__links` (a class selector which starts with a `.`) because the left hand side (`header`) is a type selector and not a class selector.

Comment: So would this work instead? ` .header {    .__links {  .a{             }     }    } `does that make them class selectors instead? sorry if I'm asking stupid questions, I'm just trying to get everything right so i don't have to go back and redo :)

Comment: That would give you `.header` instead of `header` (which would change all the things being selected) and you'd end up with `.header .__links` which still isn't what you wanted. You need the `&` is you want to combine with the previous selector and not put a descendant combinator between them.

Comment: So `.header {  &__links {     }  }` or how would you do it?

Comment: I don't know what HTML you are dealing with.

Comment: `<body> <header> <nav> <div class="header__links"><a href="#">Home</a> ...</div></nav> </header>`

Comment: `.header {  &__links {     }  }` won't match anything there.

Comment: `header { .header_links {} }` would be needed (or just `.header__links`) or just forget about that give and `header nav a {}`

Comment: Aaa ok, I see. Thanks for the help :)